# My icon theme got corrupted after installing Kdenlive

Tags: gnome, kde, icons, themes

My icon theme got corrupted after installing the Kdenlive app from the app store. I tried reinstalling it (the icon theme is called Candy-icons) from Gnome-Look but it did not help.

Here is some ScreenShots:

[image: The Light-Blue icon in the top left of the launcher is changed]

[image: The Unity3D icon is changed]

[image: The date and time app icon got changed]

And some file icons and more changed.

I think that could happen beacause I installed a KDE app in gnome. How can I fix it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain in more detail what exactly means "icon theme got corrupted". Maybe show screenshots.

Comment: It's probably not corrupted. Installing kdenlive probably switched your icon theme (this is not uncommon). Install gnome-tweaks and use that to change your icon theme back Candy-icons to test this theory.

Comment: No after redownloading and reinstalling the icon theme from gnome-look it still whas partly changed

Comment: I changed my question and aded info !